# What's the best way to synchronize a python script with a docker database container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use `docker-compose`to run a python script in one container that populates a database in a separate container. My problem is that the script launches before the database is ready to accept connections. Is there a way to avoid this and still use `docker-compose`?

My other alternative is to create a shell script that fires each of the docker container commands serially, but i would rather use `docker-compose` if possible.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
etl:
  build: ./etl
  links:
    - mysql
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: a_password
```

Here's my work-around shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:latest
docker build -t etl ./etl
docker run -it --rm -name my-etl --link mariadb:mysql etl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the etl container sleep before it starts the script, i.e.
`docker run -it --rm -name my-etl --link mariadb:mysql etl /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python your-script"`

or in Dockerfile

`CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 10 && python your-script"]`

This way the etl container will sleep for 10 seconds before it starts the python script.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed `sleep 10` is one option.

Another is to have the etl code retry the connection a few times, with a shorter sleep between each attempt (~1s).  When the connection is successful you know the container is ready, so the script can proceed.

By attempting the connection multiple times with a shorter sleep, you'll wait less time on average.

Comment: Then fail after X attempts?

Comment: Right, either after X attempts, or some period of time (ex: 30 seconds)